# Change currency of products without affecting the value

Tags: price, currency, currency-rates

How would you change the currency of a product's price within a storeview, without affecting the actual value? I would like to do this at once to all products within a store view as I have more than 5000+ products.

E.g: USD400 -> EUR400, not EUR286.77(value conversion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the currency symbol.

Navigate to

> Admin > System > Configuration > General > Currency Setup

```
Change Base Currency to  => Euro
Change Default Display Currency to => Euro
```

[image: Method 1]

Or one more Ugly way to do this. **(Not Recommented)**

> Admin > System > Manage Currency > Manage Symbol

Change the Symbol for `US Doller to EUR`
[image: Method 2]

Comment: Thanks, setting up currencies for different store views fixed my problem